# Es posible agregar el 'INTERVAL 1 MONTH' a la funcion DATE_ADD por medio de una variable. MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Saludo cordial, tengo una tabla con una columna que almacena datos de tipo varchar que son intervalos para la funcion DATE_ADD.
Ejemplo:

```
'INTERVAL 1 MONTH'
'INTERVAL 15 DAY'
```

y lo que quiero hacer es por medio de una consulta asignar uno de esos intervalos a una variable y ejecutar la funcion con el intervalo que traigo desde la BD.

```
DECLARE intervaloBD varchar(40);
SET intervaloBD = SELECT intervalo from tabla . .. 
SELECT DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, intervaloBD);
```

cabe resaltar que esto lo voy a realizar en un procedimiento almacenado.
agradezco por su atencion y ayuda.

El error es el siguiente:

```
MySQL ha dicho: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'intervaloBD);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sería muy útil si se pudiera administrar los intervalos como un tipo de datos, pero hasta dónde conozco, no es posible hacerlo. Según la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add), es posible indicar la unidad del intervalo desde una expresión, por ejemplo:

```
SET @Cantidad = 10;
SELECT DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL @Cantidad DAY);
```

Como puedes ver, solo  `@Cantidad` es lo que podrías configurar dinámicamente desde una tabla.

Para poder definir totalmente el intervalo desde una tabla, no te queda otra que trabajar con sentencias dinámicas, lo cual, deberías analizar si realmente te conviene hacer. La idea conceptual sería algo así, en primer lugar, tendríamos una tabla de intervalos, dónde cada tipo de intervalos es simplemente una cadena:

```
create table Intervalos (
    Id    int,
    Valor varchar(500)
);

insert into Intervalos (Id, Valor) values (1, '1 DAY');
insert into Intervalos (Id, Valor) values (2, '1 MONTH');
```

Y ahora construimos una sentencia a partir de la selección de alguno de los intervalos de nuestra tabla

```
select @sql := concat('SELECT DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ', I.VALOR, ')')
    from Intervalos I
    WHERE I.Id = 1;

-- en este ejemplo, la sentencia sería: SELECT DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 1 DAY)
```

Y luego simplemente habría que ejecutar de alguna forma esta sentencia, verificar [esta documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Patricio que buena Respuesta, te agradezco mucho.